How do I type this zod helper such that the return type is inferred correctly by TypeScript?
I have two helper functions I use in TypeScript in combination with the zod library. I wrote zfd first and later had a need to pass not a raw shape object, but a predefined ZodType. I tried writing a single function with variably typed arguments, but I cannot figure out the typing and always loose the specific parsed types when combining functions.
This is clearly a skill problem on my end. Hope someone can help me figure this out. I can obviously just roll with two independent functions, but other than for making the types work there isn't really a reason for that.
const zfd = <T extends z.ZodRawShape>(shape: T) => {
  return z.custom<FormData>().transform(
    (fd) => Object.fromEntries(
      fd.entries() as IterableIterator<[string, string]>
    )
  ).pipe(z.object(shape));
}

const zfdx = <T extends z.ZodTypeAny>(schema: T) => {
  return z.custom<FormData>().transform(
    (fd) => Object.fromEntries(
      fd.entries() as IterableIterator<[string, string]>
    )
  ).pipe(schema);
}

const combinedAttempt = <T extends z.ZodRawShape | z.ZodTypeAny>(schema: T) => {
  return z.custom<FormData>().transform(
    (fd) => Object.fromEntries(
      fd.entries() as IterableIterator<[string, string]>
    )
  ).pipe(schema instanceof z.ZodType ? schema : z.object(schema));
}

While the first two functions work as I'd expect them to, the last looses the typing information when parsing data and just outputs any. Would I need to overload the function or use a conditional type? In both cases I would have to explicitly declare the return types. Looking at the currently inferred return types, they look scary.

Does combinedAttempt work at runtime? Is it just the output type that's wrong?
